# Maven build error - The following artifacts could not be resolved

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3

I want to build a spring mvc project by maven, I got the following error:

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.aopalliance:com.springsource.org.aopalliance:jar:1.0.0, org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.2.0.Beta1: Could not find artifact org.aopalliance:com.springsource.org.aopalliance:jar:1.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

I use eclipse and m2eclipse plugin. I don't know how to add local repository. And I found for different versions of eclipse,the result is different. Some can pass, some fail. I am confused.

By the way where can I find the version of maven used in m2eclipse?

Update：Now I can handle hibernate-validator,but even I deleted all spring mvc dependencies,I found there are many other library are dependent  on com.springsource.org.aopalliance,
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with spring artifacts, you can refer to [this doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e684).  If you are working on released versions of spring, you can add the following repository in your settings.xml

```
   <repository>
      <id>com.springsource.repository.maven.release</id>
      <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release/</url>
      <snapshots>
          <enabled>false</enabled>
       </snapshots>
   </repository>
```

[Edit 1: based on the comment]

The groupId/projectId of aopalliance seems to indicate it is in [spring enterprise bundle repository](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/).  The contents of this accessible from the following repository url.

```
<url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/</url>
```

As for hibernate-validator, being a beta release, it is possibly not available in the normal repos. It is available from

```
<url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
```

Comment: Thanks.But this approach is not working,I still got error:Missing artifact org.aopalliance:com.springsource.org.aopalliance:jar:1.0.0:compile,Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.2.0.Beta1:compile

Comment: @Tom. Could you be behind proxy?  If so, you need to add a proxy section in your settings.xml with proxy info

Comment: Raghuram,I am not behind proxy,and I have no proxy server.

Comment: @Tom. Edited answers to provide a couple of other repository urls which holds the dependencies. You can try with these instead of what was specified earlier and see if it helps.

Comment: The repository url for hibernate works. And I found I couldn't access http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/, so I think that's why I got building error.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `%.m2\repository\org\aopalliance\com.springsource.org.aopalliance\1.0.0\`.
If there isn't a `com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar` in there, just download it by yourself and copy it to this folder.

Comment: I know that this solution is not automatically portable (I have to redo it if I move to a new computer). But hell, this answer is true :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

The version of maven used in m2eclipse can be found in Window->Preferences->Maven->Installations

It looks like the artifact cann't be found in any repository you have defined in your settings.xml or pom file. Try adding [sonatype repositories](https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#view-repositories), they have artifacts you're looking for

In your pom.xml , add :

```
  <project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype repo</id>
      <url>https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/central</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
</project>
```

However it's good practice to have its own repository manager (nexus, archiva, ...)

Comment: sorry,I still don't know how to add a repository,should I add/modify settings.xml?

Comment: pluginRepositories may work only for plugins and not for dependencies

Comment: Anyway I added the repositories which Florian F provided,but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the "external" repository to your pom.xml:

```
<repository>
    <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
    <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
</repository>
```

My complete repositories tag in pom.xml is as follows:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.maven.release</id>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```